# php inserts duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to php. I have downloaded xampp and created a database with 2 columns ID (primary key, auto-increment), CENA (INT values)

In my index.php I have just one input text and a submit button:

```
 <body>
     <form action="submit.php" method="post">
         <input type="text" name="cena"><label> cena</label>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
 </body>
```

And this is my submit script:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO updat (CENA) VALUES ('$_POST[cena]')";

mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) 
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);
```

When I enter a value into text input, and hit the submit button it echos: "1 record added"
But when I look into my databse in phpMyAdmin I see 2 records.

EXAMPLE:

I enter 123 into textinput

in phpMyAdmin I see:

```
+----+------+
| ID | CENA |
+----+------+
|  1 |  123 |
|  2 |  123 |
+----+------+
```

I am not using any loops so why 2 records?

Thank you

Comment: Please don't use user input directly in sql queries make sure you either bind values, sanitise or escape user input or your database will get hacked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is becuse you use twice `mysqli_query`:

`mysqli_query($con,$sql)`

So, first when you insert data, and after when you checking in `if()` statement, so just delete first mysql_query, for example in that way :

```
$sql="INSERT INTO updat (CENA) VALUES ('$_POST[cena]')";
 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, and what is more efficient way to check if the "submit" action was performed correctly if I will have more queries? Lets say, I will have 5 identical inputs called cena1 ... cena5 and want to submit them at once?

Comment: There several ways, you can use loop, or in as example in this way: INSERT INTO tableName (Cena) VALUES ('$_POST[cena1]'), ('$_POST[cena1]')...

Answer (score -1):

Here you are using the `INSERT` statement 2 times.

```
mysqli_query($con,$sql); //Remove this line

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Just remove one of them